# Use RecyclerView and ViewPager in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout, I need to use recyclerView and TabLayout and ViewPager in the last item in CoordinatorLayout.
but just recyclerView scroll and show, TabLayout and ViewPager don't show.
anybody can help me?

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

        <AppBarLayout>
            <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                 <Layout/>
                 <Toolbar/>
            </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
          <TabLayout/>
        </AppBarLayout>

        <ReyclerView/>
        <TabLayout/>
        <ViewPager/>

 </CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of the RecyclerView? Is it MATCH_PARENT? Try setting a smaller height to recyclerView and check whether the viewPager is visible. You need to enclose all three views inside scrollView and make recyclerView, a nested scroll.